# How can I access WebBrowser control dynamically in PowerPoint 2016 VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to access the WebBrowser control on a slide in PowerPoint 2016 VBA.

When I use Slide1.WebBrowser1, it works fine. E.g.:

```
Slide1.WebBrowser1.Navigate varURL
```

But I would like the code to work with any slide.

But when I use SSW.View.Slide I can't seem to access the WebBrowser control.  I can get the relevant Shape, but can't find a way to cast it to the WebBrowser.  This doesn't work:

```
Dim sld As Slide
Set sld = SSW.View.Slide
sld.WebBrowser1.Navigate varURL
```

I can find no variations of the above with casting or using the Shapes collection that yield a WebBrowser that I can call .Navigate on.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control is disabled by default by Microsoft since Office 2013 due to security issues. Attempting to insert it will yield the error message:

"The ActiveX control cannot be inserted."

But you can tweak the registry as per [kb2793374](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2793374) to make it work again, although inadvisable because it's a security risk and of course with the added issue that it will have to be done on every machine the presentation is viewed on.

Assuming you've done this already, the WebBrowser control object is placed on a slide object so if you want to use it on multiple slides, you'd need to duplicate the object across all the slides you want to use it on.

You can use the Navigate method from a standard code module by referencing the slide in the VBA project like this:

```
Slide1.WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://google.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, JamieG.  As I mentioned in the question, that method is working fine, and I have successfully jumped through the hoops to enable WebBrowser control.

I am creating a template, so don't want to refer to the slide explicitly as Slide1, but rather dynamically locate the WebBrowser control by starting from the Slides collection of the SlideShowWindow object.  

Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example to get a reference to the activex object - http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00042.htm. You can use a similar approach to get a reference to the web browser control.